# perform an operation on database using yesterday's and today's value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database where there is a table `wm` for water meters:

```
+------+---------------+
| Code |     name      |
+------+---------------+
| wm1  | water meter 1 |
| wm2  | water meter 2 |
| wm3  | water meter 3 |
+------+---------------+
```

and another table `counters` where  there are counters value:

```
+------+---------+-------+------------+
| Code | Code_wm | value | created_at |
+------+---------+-------+------------+
|    1 | wm1     |   100 | 2020-10-18 |
|    2 | wm1     |   0   | 2020-10-19 |
|    3 | wm2     |   0   | 2020-10-18 |
|    4 | wm2     |   100 | 2020-10-19 |
|    5 | wm3     |   0   | 2020-10-18 |
|    6 | wm3     |   100 | 2020-10-19 |
+------+---------+-------+------------+
```

i want to get this result:

```
| code_wm | result |   Date     |
+---------+--------+------------+
| wm1     | 0-100  | 2020-10-19 |
| wm2     | 100-0  | 2020-10-19 |
| wm3     | 100-0  | 2020-10-19 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

but when I try:

```
SELECT code_wm , LAG(value,1,0) OVER ( ORDER BY code_wm) as result
FROM counters
```

I don't get the correct `result`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7TuSTaukG336tqnTNDg4em/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LAG` call is missing its partition clause.  In addition, you really only want the latest data point for each code, so you need `ROW_NUMBER` here as well:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code_wm ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn,
              LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY code_wm ORDER BY created_at) lag_value
    FROM counters
)

SELECT code_wm, value || ' - ' || lag_value AS result, created_at AS Date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select code_wm,
       max(case when rn=2 then value end)||'-'||max(case when rn=1 then value end) as result,
       max(created_at) as dateval
from
(
SELECT * , row_number() OVER ( partition by code_wm order by created_at desc) as rn
FROM counters
)A group by code_wm
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find an indicative answer in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=94ebac9f586cd739803ccf0a9aa38ffd).

The created columns `Numeric_Difference` and `string_difference` are the difference in the lagging days in numeric and string depiction.
In the numeric notion, the first case is always `NULL`, so the `WHERE` clause cleans the subquery to give you your output.

The `PARTITION` would split your data base on the `code_wm` column and the `ORDER` clause helps you to order the data based on the date.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT code_wm, 
  value-LAG(value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY code_wm ORDER BY created_at) AS Numeric_Difference,
  CONCAT(CAST(value AS varchar), '-', CAST(LAG(value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY code_wm ORDER BY created_at)AS varchar)) AS string_difference,
  created_at
FROM counters)A
WHERE A.Numeric_Difference IS NOT NULL
```